# BizTalk Map XSLT to escape characters within node

Tags: xslt-1.0, biztalk, biztalk-mapper, biztalk-2013r2

I have a map with a source xml standard xml file and destination file which needs to be a flat file.

I've found an article to assist with the [conversion to string](http://stephenomo.blogspot.co.uk/2011/11/convert-xml-file-to-string-inside.html), the issue I am having now is that the output is not valid against the destination schema and I believe I need to escape the characters to get around this.  I'm looking for some help with the XSLT for that.

Source file

```
<request>
   <token>aldkfj</token>
   <sms>
      <name>name</name>
      <contact>
         <number>0123465254</number>
         <message>hello</message>
      </contact>
   </sms>
</request>
```

Destination (required)

```
<SMS>
  <HttpBody>
    <Key>xml</Key>
    <Value>&lt;request&gt&lt;token&gt;95wF-8BpA-Lnyh&lt;/token&gt;&lt;sms &gt;&lt;name&gt;test&lt;/name&gt;&lt;contact&gt;&lt;number&gt;447968296947&lt;/number&gt;&lt;/contact&gt;&lt;message&gt;API Message&lt;/message&gt;&lt;/sms&gt;&lt;/request&gt;</Value>
  </HttpBody>
</ns0:SMS>
```

Template XSLT proposed:

```
<xsl:template name="xml-to-string-called-template">
   <xsl:param name="param1" /> 
   <xsl:element name="Value"> 
      <xsl:call-template name="identity" /> 
   </xsl:element> 
</xsl:template> 
<xsl:template name="identity" match="@*|node()"> 
   <xsl:copy> 
      <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="no"> 
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" /> 
      </xsl:text> 
   </xsl:copy> 
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Found snippets online beleive this is what i am trying to achieve but not quite got it :<xsl:template name="xml-to-string-called-template">
   <xsl:param name="param1" />
          <xsl:element name="Value">
                <xsl:call-template name="identity" />
          </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="identity" match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="no">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
   </xsl:text>
    </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

Comment: Please use the [edit] link below your question to add any new information rather than in the comments where it is easy to overlook or in the case of code, hard to read.  Also show what the result is of that code, e.g. error or output (and how it differs from what you want)

Comment: Apparently you are trying to serialize the XML tree yourself. This is by no means a trivial task and is best avoided. If you really must do this, see if this can help: http://lenzconsulting.com/xml-to-string/

Comment: P.S. Note that the input you show is not well-formed XML. And the output does not seem to to make much sense either.